Assert that two files have been written correctly
How would I assert that this function wrote to those files in tests?
def write() -> None:
    with open('./foo', 'w') as f:
        f.write('fooo')
    with open('./bar', 'w') as f:
        f.write('baar')

class Test:
    @patch('builtins.open', idk)
    def test_write(self, something: MagicMockOrSomething) -> None:
        write()
        something.assert_somehow_foo_contains_fooo()
        something.assert_somehow_bar_contains_baar()

I'd like to use the decorator syntax with @patch if possible.
The documentation only shows it for one file, and not using the decorator: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open

The write method returns the number of characters actually written, so you should capture that value. You can also read the file back to check its contents.

It would be good if the test doesn't actually write to the disk. If I am able to mock it so that I can test for the bytes written, I'll most likely also be able to assert the parameters passed to it. The question is, how I can somehow use mock_open or something similar to do that.

Unless you have a strong reason, should not try to test internals of your language/library/framework etc, it's the responsibility of its development team.

The code above is just a minimal example for reproduction, the actual code is more complicated. I'm assuming you thought I am writing unittests that test if python works as expected? Of course not.

As explained in the mock_open documentation, there are helpers to get the write information.
The issue is that even if you mock out the call to open() it is the returned 
object that is used as a context manager (and has __enter__() and __exit__() 
called).
 
Mocking context managers with a MagicMock is common enough and fiddly enough 
that a helper function is useful.

So to test multiple write calls, you can use:
handle = open_mock()
handle.write.assert_has_calls(...)

This is the full code I used to test this:
import unittest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch, mock_open, call

def write() -> None:
    with open('./foo', 'w') as f:
        f.write('fooo')
    with open('./bar', 'w') as f:
        f.write('baar')



class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("builtins.open", new_callable=mock_open)
    def test_write(self, open_mock: MagicMock) -> None:
        write()

        self.assertEquals(2, open_mock.call_count)
        open_mock.assert_has_calls(
            [
                call('./foo', 'w'),
                call('./bar', 'w'),
            ],
            any_order=True,
        )
        handle = open_mock()
        handle.write.assert_has_calls(
            [
                call('fooo'),
                call('baar'),
            ]
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

To test the correct order of the opens and writes, you'll also need to include the context manager __enter__ and __exit__ calls. e.g.
import unittest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch, mock_open, call


def write() -> None:
    with open("./foo", "w") as f:
        f.write("fooo")
    with open("./bar", "w") as f:
        f.write("baar")


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("builtins.open", new_callable=mock_open)
    def test_write(self, open_mock: MagicMock) -> None:
        write()

        self.assertEquals(2, open_mock.call_count)
        open_mock.assert_has_calls(
            [
                call("./foo", "w"),
                call().__enter__(),
                call().write("fooo"),
                call().__exit__(None, None, None),
                call("./bar", "w"),
                call().__enter__(),
                call().write("baar"),
                call().__exit__(None, None, None),
            ],
        )



if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()


Thanks. But if ./foo contained baar this would pass, right?

Because the open_mock as the context manager calls in the calls list so that is why that has any_order=True.  If you test for those calls also, then you can test the order also. I'll do an update to the answer.

There seems to be no solution that is both easy and flexible. open_mock.mock_calls (Don't do open_mock().mock_calls, otherwise you won't get the calls to open the file) contains operations on all files
You can test for fixed indices in the mock_calls list. Something like
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

class Test:
    @patch("builtins.open")
    def test_write(self, open_mock: MagicMock) -> None:
        write()

        assert open_mock.mock_calls[0][1] == ('./foo', 'w')
        assert open_mock.mock_calls[2][1] == ('fooo',)

        assert open_mock.mock_calls[4][1] == ('./bar', 'w')
        assert open_mock.mock_calls[6][1] == ('baar',)


Or, if you require something more sophisticated, you can use this helper function, though I'd strongly recommend to keep your tests as simple as possible:
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

class Test:
    @patch("builtins.open")
    def test_write(self, open_mock: MagicMock) -> None:
        write()
        self.assert_written_to_file(
            open_mock,
            "./foo",
            "fooo"
        )
        self.assert_written_to_file(
            open_mock,
            "./bar",
            "baar"
        )

    def assert_written_to_file(
        self,
        open_mock: MagicMock,
        path: str,
        payload: str,
        mode: str = "w",
    ) -> None:
        open_mock.assert_any_call(path, mode)

        # There may be multiple calls to open files in the call history.
        # After a call to open a file, it is followed by a call to `__enter__()`, until
        # it is closed with `__exit__()`. Find all calls between enter and exit.
        file_opened = False
        write_calls = []
        for call in open_mock.mock_calls:
            print(call[0], call[1])
            if call[0] == "" and call[1] == (path, mode):
                file_opened = True

            if call[0] == "().__enter__().write" and file_opened:
                write_calls.append(call)

            if file_opened and call[0] == "().__exit__":
                # Other files may be opened afterward.
                break

        written_payloads = [call[1][0] for call in write_calls]
        if payload not in written_payloads:
            raise AssertionError(
                f'Could not find call to save payload "{payload}" in {written_payloads}'
            )

Using mock_open didn't really bring any benefit to this it seems. If you are using it, you need to test for ().write, not ().__enter__().write.
